# Unit testing ASP.NET Web API 2 Controller which returns custom result

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API 2 controller which has an action method like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Foo(int id)
{
    var foo = await _repository.GetFooAsync(id);
    return foo == null ? (IHttpActionResult)NotFound() : new CssResult(foo.Css);
}
```

Where `CssResult` is defined as:

```
public class CssResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly string _content;

    public CssResult(string content)
    {
        content.ShouldNotBe(null);
        _content = content;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(_content, Encoding.UTF8, "text/css")
        };

        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

How do i write a unit test for this?

I tried this:

```
var response = await controller.Foo(id) as CssResult;
```

But i don't have access to the actual content, e.g i want to verify that the actual content of the response is the CSS i expect.

Any help please?

Is the solution to simply make the `_content` field public? (that feels dirty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid casts, especially in unit tests.
This should work:

```
var response = await controller.Foo(id);
var message = await response.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None);
var content = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Assert.AreEqual("expected CSS", content);
```